# Is Hinduism a "religion" or not?

Tags: history

Many people around the globe stated that Hinduism is not a religion. Hinduism contain one single god with different forms. Why is that a god can't function all the different functions? Many believers of Hinduism say that they have many gods by not accepting the mentioned statement. why is this ?

Comment: I didn't get this part: *"Many believers of Hinduism say that they have many gods by not accepting the mentioned statement. why is this ?"* Could you explain what do you mean by *"by not accepting the mentioned statement."* ?

Comment: Actually, I think it is the other way around. Many hindus claim that Hinduism is not a religion.